# why an accessor method in an ARC environment cannot have a name that begins with 'new'?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

[this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/index.html) document states that, in order to cooperates with codes written in a MRR(manual retain-release) environment, codes written in an ARC environment cannot have a accessor name that begins with "new", I can't figure out why ARC puts this restriction on method naming.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can! See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family.attribute However, it's probably unwise to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the cause is because of this:

> 5.2.1. Semantics of init
>
> Methods in the init family implicitly consume their self parameter and return a retained object. Neither of these properties can be altered through attributes.
>
> A call to an init method with a receiver that is either self (possibly parenthesized or casted) or super is called a delegate init call. It is an error for a delegate init call to be made except from an init method, and excluding blocks within such methods.
>
> As an exception to the usual rule, the variable self is mutable in an init method and has the usual semantics for a __strong variable. However, it is undefined behavior and the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if an init method attempts to use the previous value of self after the completion of a delegate init call. It is conventional, but not required, for an init method to return self.
>
> It is undefined behavior for a program to cause two or more calls to init methods on the same object, except that each init method invocation may perform at most one delegate init call.

Source: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family.semantics.init

Method names starting with **new** by convention used to call both the alloc and init methods in the past and I believe there are still methods used in Apple's framwork with the 'new' convention. I guess ARC still takes this into account with regards to memory management.

Also read up on the following: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family

> An Objective-C method may fall into a method family, which is a conventional set of behaviors ascribed to it by the Cocoa conventions.
>
> A method is in a certain method family if:
>
> - it has a objc_method_family attribute placing it in that family; or if not that,
> - it does not have an objc_method_family attribute placing it in a different or no family, and
> - its selector falls into the corresponding selector family, and
> - its signature obeys the added restrictions of the method family.
>
> A selector is in a certain selector family if, ignoring any leading underscores, the first component of the selector either consists entirely of the name of the method family or it begins with that name followed by a character other than a lowercase letter. For example, _perform:with: and performWith: would fall into the perform family (if we recognized one), but performing:with would not.
>
> The families and their added restrictions are:
>
> - alloc methods must return a retainable object pointer type.
> - copy methods must return a retainable object pointer type.
> - mutableCopy methods must return a retainable object pointer type.
> - new methods must return a retainable object pointer type.
> - init methods must be instance methods and must return an Objective-C pointer type.
>
> Additionally, a program is ill-formed if it declares or contains a call to an init method whose return type is neither id nor a pointer to a super-class or sub-class of the declaring class (if the method was declared on a class) or the static receiver type of the call (if it was declared on a protocol).

I guess the above means you could call a method something like **newobject** instead of **newObject** to avoid the mechanisms of ARC, but that might not make much sense for anyone working with your code. Perhaps you could also avoid the usual memory rules by setting an attribute on your custom **new*** method that forces some other method family on the property.